# What is the value of absolute zero: $-273.15\ \rm °C$ or $-273.16\ \rm °C$?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, metrology

What is the value of [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero)?

0K=
-273.15 °C 
Or 
-273.16 °C

It has been confused in different scientific scriptures. The [first definition on Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/absolute-zero), for example.

Comment: The triple point is the reference. It is at 0.01 C, probably that is where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @user54826 I think it's an acceptable question: [Some popular sites](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/absolute-zero) do say the incorrect answer, and it's reasonable to not be sure that dictionary.com is not a reliable scientific source.

Comment: @Chair there are 4 mentions of -273.15°C on the dictionary.com page for absolute zero, and only one for -273.16°C. Otherwise a simple google search yields the answer, as I wrote. Or a visit to Wikipedia, etc.

Comment: @Chair Google displays the content of Dictionary.com, there is no need to click on the link itself, and the result displayed is the correct one.

Comment: @user54826 You can cast a close vote/flag if you believe the prior research is poor enough (I don't think it is too bad a question). We disagree about the prevalence of incorrect resources and that's how it goes; though your case is not without justification. Maybe 5 users with 3k rep will vote to close this, I wouldn't be surprised if that happens. But arguing over minutiae is pointless.

Answer (score 8):

According to BIPM (International Bureau of Weights and Measures),

> The kelvin, unit of thermodynamic temperature, is the fraction $\frac{1}{273.16}$ of the thermodynamic temperature of the triple point of water.

Hence the triple point of water is $273.16\ \rm K$. Comparing to the $0.01\ \rm °C$ reference (i.e. $273.16\ \mathrm{K}$ is the same as $0.01\ \mathrm{°C}$), we see that absolute zero is $-273.15\ °\rm C$.

BIPM is reliable; see [this page on their website about the Kelvin scale](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/kelvin.html). They're the group which publishes the SI brochure.